# What is the filler phrase some French keep saying that is pronounced like German word "lecker"?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, oral

I suppose the meaning must be something like 'easy' or 'okay' or 'I see' or but there are tons of possibilities.

The sound of it is pretty much like the German word "lecker".

Comment: Maybe you could find a and post a link to eg a youtube clip where you can hear this phrase ?

Comment: I think you might have heard "*D'accord*", I don't see anything closer.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Ah yes, maybe "L'accord", that could be it! Thanks

Comment: *L'accord* doesn't make sense, *d'accord* does a lot.

Comment: ***L'équerre***

Comment: @Bregalad as a filler ??

Comment: @jlliagre Are expressions like that absolutely never used in casual conversations? I noticed that in several languages, people will use noun to come off cool.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 - /ˈlɛkɐ/. I heard that among people from south of France who have lived internationally for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one expression that can be used as a filler in French and which phonetics is close enough to the German *Lecker*.

It is the expression ***d'accord***, suggested by Teleporting Goat in his comment. *D'accord* meaning is close to *Okay*. It is commonly used either to tell you understand what was just said, or to ask if what you said is understood.

Here are some examples:

Emmanuel Macron: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OB4gkK4H3yE

Danyel Gérard: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EF6huS24u8

Omar Sy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTWcQbUAZDQ

The other suggestion *l'équerre* is phonetically closer, but cannot be used as a filler where it would make absolutely no sense.